# No SPROM available error when installing Ubuntu from USB

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to install the latest version of Ubunto on to my computer so I can duel boot with windows 10. Every time I try to boot from the memory stick from bios in bios and uefi mode it gives the same error. No sprom available.

Any help?

Error screen:

[image]

Comment: [Sounds like you have an incompatible hardware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736600/id-0x4360-rev-0x03-and-package-0x01-analog-12-type-11-ac-revision-1)

Comment: `bcma` is the driver for your WLAN adapter. You should be able to boot without WLAN, but more serious are the following errors for `nouveau`, the driver for Nvidia graphics card. Try to add a kernel option to boot with vga framebuffer instead of nouveau (google for details).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this I first disable the WLAN module from bios then proceeded to add the nouveau.modeset=0 to the end of the linux line in the GNU kernel. This allowed me to boot into the test mode and install from there. Once this had been done I was able to install the drivers from Additional Drivers application. Everything now works.